# Cold water not flowing to certain areas in the house

Tags: plumbing

The water main busted and after it was repaired we no longer have cold water in the front bathroom, the back bathrooms toilet or shower but still have cold water through out the rest of the house.

No chance in frozen pipes as it's summer in Texas.
We have blown air through the pipes to check for blockage, some buildup came out but did not fix the issue.

Why would only some areas not have cold water flow when the fixture next to it does?
What else do we need to be looking for to fix?

Comment: It is possible that the pipes are open but debris has blocked the fixtures?  You say you blew air through the pipes, did it free-flow or was it restricted?  More information would really help.